# How can I insert the result of 3 select statements on 3 tables into a new table in Hive?

Tags: select, insert, hive

```
select sum(column_table1) from table1 where job_run_time_stamp >= '2016-12-15 00:00:00' and job_run_time_stamp < '2016-12-16 00:00:00';
select sum(column_table2) from table2 where job_run_time_stamp >= '2016-12-15 00:00:00' and job_run_time_stamp < '2016-12-16 00:00:00';
select sum(column_table3) from table3 where job_run_time_stamp >= '2016-12-15 00:00:00' and job_run_time_stamp < '2016-12-16 00:00:00';
```

How can I combine the above 3 query results and put them into a 4th table (as 3 different columns) called `table4` in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

Following can work

```
insert into table4
values(
select sum(t.sum1) , sum(t.sum2), sum(t.sum3) from 
(select sum(column_table1) as sum1 , 0 as sum2, 0 as sum3 from table1 where     job_run_time_stamp >= '2016-12-15 00:00:00' and job_run_time_stamp < '2016-12-16 00:00:00'
union
select 0, sum(column_table2) , 0 from table2 where job_run_time_stamp >= '2016-12-15 00:00:00' and job_run_time_stamp < '2016-12-16 00:00:00' 
union
select 0,0, sum(column_table3) from table3 where job_run_time_stamp >= '2016-12-15 00:00:00' and job_run_time_stamp < '2016-12-16 00:00:00') as t
)
```